# how to use more than one @modelattribute on spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean,user user 
            BindingResult result)

I want to add 2 model attributes one is related to store emoloyee information and one for storing user login for the emloyee,accoring to my program i don't want to make any relationship with employee and user table due to some restriction on my project,please help me out,how can i use 2 model attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass in `Model` as an argument to your method then just refer to that to add more than one attribute.

Like this:

```
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@Model model, EmployeeBean employeeBean,
    User user BindingResult result) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("employeeBean", new EmployeeBean());
}
```